# Derek Banas tutorial: Didn't find class "android.view.button"

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm currently following Derek Banas's tutorial 1 (url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw)
and i have some errors shown in the log cat. Basically, there's a known issure about the fragment xml and i've solved it. the problem is when there's no errors on my project (no x or ! sign), whenever i run, the app unfortunately stops on my eclipse virtual device.

here is my logcat:

```
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1065
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class button
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class button
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     ... 11 more
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.button" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myfirstapp-1, /system/lib]]
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
06-28 15:21:08.164: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     ... 24 more
```

Hope someone's able to help me. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Can you please show your MainActivity code? It is crashing on line 23 of that class.

Comment: @joao2fast4u here's my main code between line 20-23. the rest is too long to put :)

    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 4):

In your layout xml file use `Button` instead of `button`.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating the main activity layout and it fail because the class `android.view.button` cannot be found.

Your layout (xml) contains probably a tag `<button>` and that's wrong : change it to `<Button>`